# Find component by type in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uicomponents

My question is related to this one [Get all hidden input fields in JSF dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545336/get-all-hidden-input-fields-in-jsf-dynamically) but it's not the same as I want to work with JSF and not plain HTML, and assuming that I have the following in my `.xhtml` file:

```
<h:inputHidden id="name1" value="SomeValue1"/>
<h:inputHidden id="name2" value="SomeValue2"/>
```

I developed a small code where I tried to get all the `h:inputHidden` tags dynamically and print their values to the console, but the problem is that I can't figure out a way how to make everythning dynamic. In my code I should know the form `id` if I want to Iterate over the uicomponents, how can I iterate over all the `UIComponent` in the component tree ? (I tried `UIViewRoot#getChildren()` but i get only the first childrens).

Here is the code snippet:

```
// formId is the id of my form
List<UIComponent> components = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("formId").getChildren();
// A List of UIComponent where I am adding my Hidden Inputs
List<UIComponent> hiddenComponents = new ArrayList<UIComponent>();

for (UIComponent component : components) {

    // using the hidden inputs type in JSF: HtmlInputHidden
    if (component instanceof HtmlInputHidden) {
        hiddenComponents.add(component);
    }

}

for (UIComponent component : hiddenComponents) {

    // Printing the hidden inputs values for demonstration purposes
    System.out.println(((HtmlInputHidden)component).getValue());

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You also need to iterate over children of children, and their children, etcetera. You see, it's a component **tree**.

Here's a kickoff snippet of an utility method which does exactly that using [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call):

```
public static <C extends UIComponent> void findChildrenByType(UIComponent parent, List<C> found, Class<C> type) {
    for (UIComponent child : parent.getChildren()) {
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(child.getClass())) {
            found.add(type.cast(child));
        }

        findChildrenByType(child, found, type);
    }
}
```

Here's how you could use it:

```
UIForm form = (UIForm) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("formId");
List<HtmlInputHidden> hiddenComponents = new ArrayList<>();
findChildrenByType(form, hiddenComponents, HtmlInputHidden.class);

for (HtmlInputHidden hidden : hiddenComponents) {
    System.out.println(hidden.getValue());
}
```

Or, better, use [`UIComponent#visitTree()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#visitTree(javax.faces.component.visit.VisitContext,%20javax.faces.component.visit.VisitCallback)) which uses the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). The major difference is that it also iterates over iterating components such as `<ui:repeat>` and `<h:dataTable>` and restores the child state for every iteration. Otherwise you would end up getting no value when you have an `<h:inputHidden>` enclosed in such component.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
List<Object> hiddenComponentValues = new ArrayList<>();
context.getViewRoot().findComponent("formId").visitTree(VisitContext.createVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {
    @Override
    public VisitResult visit(VisitContext visitContext, UIComponent component) {
        if (component instanceof HtmlInputHidden) {
            hiddenComponentValues.add(((HtmlInputHidden) component).getValue());
            return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
        } else {
            return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
        }
    }
});

for (Object hiddenComponentValue : hiddenComponentValues) {
    System.out.println(hiddenComponentValue);
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to collect values of an UIInput component inside an UIData component in bean's action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665385/how-to-collect-values-of-an-uiinput-component-inside-an-uidata-component-in-bean/)
- [How do I attach a FacesMessage from the backing bean to a specific field in a ui:repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131583/how-do-i-attach-a-facesmessage-from-the-backing-bean-to-a-specific-field-in-a-ui/)
- [Accessing dynamic UIComponents in JSF Managed Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573168/accessing-dynamic-uicomponents-in-jsf-managed-bean/)
- [JSF 2 -- Save All Valid Component Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742512/jsf-2-save-all-valid-component-values/)

After all, it's probably easiest to just bind them to a bean property the usual way, if necessary inside an `<ui:repeat>`:

```
<h:inputHidden id="name1" value="#{bean.name1}"/>
<h:inputHidden id="name2" value="#{bean.name2}"/>
```

Comment: So I can call the `findComponentsByType()` method on the UIViewRoot directly? in case i don't konw the form ID ? e.g: `findComponentsByType(context.getViewRoot(), hiddenComponents, HtmlInputHidden.class);` is this correct ? also can we do the same with `visitTree` ?

Comment: You can do so. It's also an `UIComponent` anyway. Note that I slightly renamed method/argument names to improve self-documentability.

Comment: Yes I just noticed that, one last question and sorry for bothering you:  UIComponent#visitTree() could we also invoke it directly on `context.getViewRoot()` ?

Comment: `UIViewRoot` **is** an `UIComponent`.

Comment: I think you forgot to modify the `findComponentsByType` name inside the `findChildrenByType` function.